# Visual Studio Installer - property edit before install

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-project

I'm creating my first installer with Visual Studio and I'm trying to wrap my head around it, but I've hit a wall with this issue.

I have my files I want to install, but I want to install them to a specific folder, namely the panels folder in the Photoshop directory e.g. C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC (64 Bit)\Plug-ins\Panels

So I put in a Launch Condition - File Search for Photoshop.exe. This works great and my property (PHOTOSHOPEXISTS) does indeed return the path C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe.
I want to take that property and turn it into the Panels directory above but I can't figure out how to edit it. Is there a way to edit the PHOTOSHOPEXISTS property before I do the install?

Answer (score 0):

In the File System on Target Machine view, you right-click that File System on Target Machine=>Add special folder and select Custom Folder. In the properties window for that custom folder you can leave the DefaultLocation as [TARGETDIR] but put your PHOTOSHOPEXISTS as the Property value. Then just add your files to that custom folder.